# Is everything in an animated TV show copyrighted?

Tags: copyright

let's use *Futurama* as the example. I understand all the characters are copyrighted. What about certain objects like slurm? or the holophonor?

Are all objects in the whole duration in the episode copyrighted?

Answer (score 4):

Each episode of the show as a whole, and all the individual images in it, are protected by copyright, but the idea of a holophonor, or indeed any idea, is not. The more closely anyone else's drawing of a gadget resembles one from the show, the more likely it would be to be found to infringe copyright. The same is true of a character image. The more distinctive and original the image, and the more closely someone copies it, the more likely a finding of infringement would be.

Comment: Yes. Copyright protects images; it does not protect concepts or devices.

Comment: @bdb484 Copyright protects "creative works". It isn't restricted to any particular medium.

Comment: @TylerH  that is not quite true, at least under US law. There is a limited set of kinds of things that copyright protects. It doesn't depend on the medium, but it does depend on the nature of the work. A single coined word may be highly creative, such as "xerox", or "kodak", or "hobbit" but it will not be protected by copyright. The design of a new machine may be highly creative, but it will be protected, if at all, by patent law, not by copyright. Recipes for cooking  are generally not protected. See 17 USC 102 for the 8 general categories of protectable works.

Comment: thank you all for the response. I am looking forward to getting a license to sell products based on shows. I'm not sure how ip and rights work but is some stuff more valuable than others? example: getting the rights to fry and bender will cost $10,000 and the rights to a holophonor may cost $2,000. or is it all one set price?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Your comment doesn't seem to indicate anything about mine is untrue. If anything it only supports it. The important part to consider is the definition of 'creative works' which is what copyright as an instrument was created to serve. My point above was to make sure OP and future readers did not confuse "Copyright" with "legal *image* protection", exclusively.

Comment: @Kushimaru The holder of copyright may make whatever terms s/he pleases for any particular license, there is no standard. The holder may set separate prices for the right to copy or adapt particular images, or set a single comprehensive price  for the right to copy anything in the show, or decline to grant any license at any price. I would rather expect the third, but there is no way to know except to ask.

Comment: @TylerH  Indeed copyright protects more than images, if anything it protects texts more often than images. The comment by  bdb484  could have been misread as saying that it only protects images. My reply was because your comment could be read as saying that copyright protects **all** creative works. I wanted to point out some of the many things that are creative works but are not protected by copyright. Copyright was originally designed to protect printers' monopolies, and the modern uses of copyright were developed gradually.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Yes, my comment was incomplete because it was intended to address only the facts relevant to OP's actual question. TylerH appears to have attempted to correct that comment by adding his own imprecisions.